# Set intersection in a loop

Tags: c++, stl, for-loop, set, intersection

My function `search_intersection` receive a set `<set<string> >& inter_section`.

I want get the intersection over all subsets in `inter_section`.

For example if:

```
inter_section = { { lion, cat } , {lion, bird}, {lion, cat, bird} }
```

I want:

```
result = { lion }
```

At the moment I did this

```
  set<string> search_intersection(set <set<string> >& inter_section)
  {

  set <set<string> >::iterator iter_ss;

  set <string>  result;


  for (iter_ss = inter_section.begin(); iter_ss != inter_section.end(); ++iter_ss)
        {
         set_intersection(iter_ss.begin(),iter_ss.end(),
         result.begin(),result.end(),
          std::inserter(result.begin(),result.end()));
   }

    cout <<  endl;

    return result;
   }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the question here?

If I had to guess, I would say that your code doesn't work because you initialize `result` to be empty, when time you intersect the empty set with anything, you get the empty set.
  
Try setting the result to the first set in the list, and then iterate starting with the second one.

Comment: Hello Marshall, it's a good sugestion. I tried iterate with the second element (withou sucess) in follow way (please look that this is not the exact code that I post before)                           iter_s = keys.begin();
     std::advance(iter_s, 1);
     for (; iter_s != keys.end(); ++iter_s)
     {
        aux = search_sucess(index, iter_s);
        std::set_intersection(aux.begin(), aux.end(),    inter_section.begin(), inter_section.end(),
        std::inserter(inter_section, intersecao.end()));
     }

Comment: iter_s = keys.begin(); std::advance(iter_s, 1); for (; iter_s                != keys.end(); ++iter_s) { aux = search_sucess(index, iter_s);std::set_intersection(aux.begin(), aux.end(), inter_section.begin(), inter_section.end(), std::inserter(inter_section, intersecao.end())); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try again: (Uncompiled code)

```
set<string> search_intersection(const set <set<string> > &inter_section) {
   set <string>  result;
   set <set<string> >::iterator iter = inter_section.begin ();
   if ( iter != inter_section.end ()) {
      result = *iter;
      for ( ++iter; iter != inter_section.end (); ++iter ) {
         set <string>  temp;
      // intersect *iter and result, put into temp
         set_intersection(
            iter->begin(),  iter->end (),
            result.begin(), result.end(),
            std::inserter(temp,temp.end()));
         result = temp;
         }
   }

   return result;
}
```

Note that the call to set_intersection passes the begin/end of the set pointed to by the iterator. Also, there are at least two places where `const` should be applied to this code.

You can't write the results of `set_intersection` into one of the inputs, either. Hence a temp variable.